# how can I get the data of cached images SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage library to cache web images in my UICollectionView:

```
cell.packItemImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: smileImageUrl[indexPath.row]))
```

but I want to save the cached images locally in a file instead of downloading them again

```
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: newPath, contents: Data(contentsOf:  URL(string: snapchildvalue[Constants.smiles.smileImageUrl] as! String)!), attributes: nil)
```

is there a way to get the data of cached images

Answer (score 27):

`SDWebImage` caches downloaded images automatically by default. You can use `SDImageCache` to retrieve images from the cache. There is a memory cache for the current app session, which will be quicker, and there is the disk cache. Example usage:

```
if let image = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromDiskCache(forKey: imageURL.absoluteString) {
//use image
}

if let image = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromMemoryCache(forKey: imageURL.absoluteString) {
//use image
}
```

Also make sure you `import SDWebImage` in your file. (If you're using Swift/Carthage, it will be `import WebImage`

Answer (score 5):

SDWebimage chaches image once it is downloaded from a url. Basically it saves image against a url and next time if an image is available for a URL. It will simply get that image from cache. So the below method will be called instantly if the image is already downloaded to device.

```
    imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:url), completed: { (image, error, type, url) in
         imgView.image = image
         //Do any thing with image here. This will be called instantly after image is downloaded to cache. E.g. if you want to save image (Which is not required for a simple image fetch, 
         //you can use FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: newPath, contents: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), attributes: nil)
     })
```

Still if you want to save that image somewhere else or modify it or whatever, you can do it in the completion block above.

Comment: what is imgView how can I define it in swift code?

Comment: @Markon UIImageView

Answer (score 3):

`SDWebImage` already have this kind of caching file locally

1. Create a `SDImageCache` with namespace of your choice
2. Try get the image with `imageCache.queryDiskCache`
3. If the image exist, set it to your imageview, if not, use `sd_setImage` to get the image then save it to the local cache with `SDImageCache.shared().store`

The key usually to be the image url string

Something like this, might not be correct syntax:

```
imageCache.queryDiskCache(forKey: urlForImageString().absoluteString, done: {(_ image: UIImage, _ cacheType: SDImageCacheType) -> Void in
    if image {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
    else {
        self.imageView.sd_setImage(withURL: urlForImageString(), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder")!, completed: {(_ image: UIImage, _ error: Error, _ cacheType: SDImageCacheType, _ imageURL: URL) -> Void in
            SDImageCache.shared().store(image, forKey: urlForImageString().absoluteString)
        })
    }
})
```